# Composite foreign key JPA TypeMismatchException

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys, key, composite-key

I've explained my scenario through simple Parent Child tables.

My composite primary key is also a composite foreign key referencing Parent table.

```
create table parent(
code varchar(10) not null,
id int not null,
parentcol varchar(10),
primary key(code,id)
);

create table child(
code varchar(10) not null,
id int not null,
childcol varchar(10) not null,
primary key(code, id),
foreign key(code, id) references parent(code,id)
);
```

Entities created (this is through Eclipse JPA plugin)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
@NamedQuery(name="Parent.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Parent p")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ParentPK id;

@Column(length=10)
private String parentcol;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to Child
@OneToOne(mappedBy="parent")
private Child child;

public Parent() {
}

/* getters and setters */

}

@Embeddable
public class ParentPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
private String code;

@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

    /* getters and setters */

/** Overridden equals and hashcode **/
}



@Entity
@Table(name="child")
@NamedQuery(name="Child.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Child c")
public class Child implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ChildPK id;

@Column(nullable=false, length=10)
private String childcol;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to Parent
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
private Parent parent;

    /* getters and setters */

}

@Embeddable
public class ChildPK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
private String code;

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

/* overridden equals and hashcode */
```

I am using Spring data to save my entities as below. Parent table consist of a record with code as "code" and Id as 1.

```
Child child = new Child();
ChildPK childPK = new ChildPK();
childPK.setCode("code");
childPK.setId(1);
child.setId(childPK);
child.setChildcol("child1");
childRepository.save(child);
```

It succeeds with the 1st run when it has to insert a new record. But the issue is on the 2nd run when it has to update let's say with,

```
child.setChildcol("child2");
```

I face an error

```
HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.xebia.eTechLog.entities.Parent. Expected: class com.xebia.eTechLog.entities.ParentPK, got class com.xebia.eTechLog.entities.ChildPK
```

In case I try to give a reference of ParentPk in the Child table as

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
@NamedQuery(name="Child.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Child c")
public class Child implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ParentPK id;

@Column(nullable=false, length=10)
private String childcol;

//bi-directional one-to-one association to Parent
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
private Parent parent;
```

It does work, but it won't in case there are more fields in the Parent class, which is my real scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a derived identity. Which means you should indicate that the child's reference to its parent maps the child's ID (with a `@MapsId` annotation):

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ChildPK id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=10)
    private String childcol;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId  // <<< NB
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="code", referencedColumnName="code"),
        @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
    })
    private Parent parent;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I was able to figure out the answer before, and it is quite in line with what you've mentioned. You need to use a @MapsId for the part of the composite primary key which maps to Parent table.